# Seeing Groupby results

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am looking at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html   They have a simple example I don't understand.

```
speeds = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ("bird", "Falconiformes", 389.0),
        ("bird", "Psittaciformes", 24.0),
        ("mammal", "Carnivora", 80.2),
        ("mammal", "Primates", np.nan),
        ("mammal", "Carnivora", 58),
    ],
    index=["falcon", "parrot", "lion", "monkey", "leopard"],
    columns=("class", "order", "max_speed"),
)

grouped = speeds.groupby("class")
```

How do I see the results?

```
print(grouped)
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7f99d8d10dd0>

grouped.head()
```

returns the unchanged dataframe.    The example seems incomplete but I'm afraid I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Have you tried commands like `grouped.first()` or `grouped.sum()` as advised below on the same page. You writing `grouped.head()` suggest you believe `grouped` is a dataframe, however a `pandas.api.typing.DataFrameGroupBy` object is no dataframe. The example indeed isn't incomplete: it is being developped throughout the page.

Comment: I agree, that section is confusing. They give one example then immediately follow it up with another example that restates some of the same things but goes more in-depth.

Comment: OK, grouped.first() show part of the object.   How do I see the whole thing?  As for further down the page, they change the data.  Nowhere down the page do I see the whole thing after groupby.